# How can I set the alignment of the arrows on a QTreeWidgetItem

Tags: qt, pyside, qtreeview, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

[image]

**I want these TreeWidget Arrows to align with the top of the TreeWidgetItem.**

I've got a `QtWidgets.QTreeWidget()`, and have created a custom `QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem()`.

I then set a custom Item widget `self.tree_widget.setItemWidget(self.tree_widget_item, 0, self.main_widget)`

As a result the decorator / arrow positions itself evenly in the center of the geometry, however I want it to be aligned at the top.

I've been looking into setting the alignment for this, but am not 100% sure where to set it, or if I need to set it through a style sheet. If I'm unable to move this I can create a custom widget to replace the decorator, and hide the default ones, but I'd prefer to use what's here if possible.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reimplement `QTreeView.drawBranches` and set a smaller height to the QRect used to draw each branch. Simply using the width is a good value if the arrows are symmetrical.

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *

class Tree(QTreeWidget):

    def drawBranches(self, painter, rect, index):
        rect.setHeight(rect.width())
        super().drawBranches(painter, rect, index)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tree = Tree()
    for i in range(5):
        item = QTreeWidgetItem([f'Item {i}\n\n'])
        item.addChild(QTreeWidgetItem([f'Child {i}']))
        tree.addTopLevelItem(item)
    tree.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Before    |    After:

[image]      [image]

Comment: Perfect, this does exactly what I want. Thanks!
Shame it has to be it's own class, but maybe it's better / cleaner this way!
I had to write the super slightly differently, but this is most likely down to the version of Python I'm using: super(CustomTreeWidget, self).drawBranches(painter, rect, index)